# Question regarding a proof from previous post.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, riemann-sum

Regarding [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3590416/calculate-upper-riemann-sum-for-fx-x2-for-x-in-0-1) answer, how did we get that the $M_i = \left(\frac in\right)^2$, where the $M_i$ is defined in the linked post.

Comment: Partition the interval $[0, 1]$ into $n$ equal parts, each of length $1/n$. Then the partition points are at $1/n, 2/n, 3/n, \dots$, so in general $i/n$. Plug this into $f(x) = x^2$ and you get $(i/n)^2$.

Comment: As to why that's the sup on $[(i-1)/n, i/n]$, note that $f(x) = x^2$ is increasing for $x > 0$.

Comment: Ok, you have answered my questions. Thank, I forget that one! I appreciate it!

Comment: If you want to post an answer I can accept it :)

Comment: Sure, done, @Seong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $f(x) = x^2$ is increasing on the $i$th interval $[\frac{i - 1}{n}, \frac{i}{n}]$, the largest value it attains is the value at the right end-point, in this case $M_i = f(\frac{i}{n}) = (\frac{i}{n})^2$.